# Return all tags based on context - ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using the rails gem acts-as-taggable on, and am tagging posts on two contexts: tags and topics.

To return a hash of all the topics tags used so far for posts I can use the code:

```
 Post.tag_counts_on(:topics)
```

However, I have created a certain number of set topics tags, and if some of these topics tags aren't currently being used as tags on posts, then the code above doesn't return the said topics.

I am wondering if there is a way to return all the relevant tags based on context -- I was hoping for a solution along the lines of :

```
 topics = Tag.topics
```

To implement the solution, I created a Tag.rb model:

```
 class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :relationship_topics, :foreign_key => "topic_followed_id", :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :topic_followers, :through => :relationship_topics, :source => :topic_follower
 end
```

Here I have some code to allow for following topics, but nothing more.

Does anyone know how I could return all the tags based on context?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have never used [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) but a quick browse through of the code suggests, you can do:

```
# to get all the tags with context topic with counts
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.
    includes(:tag).
    where(:context => "topics").
    group("tags.name").
    select("tags.name, COUNT(*) as count")
```

You should probably take a look at [ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tagging.rb), [ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb) and the migration file in your db/migrations folder to figure out how you can go about it.

If you don't want the count, only the tag names:

```
tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.includes(:taggings).
           where("taggings.context = 'topics'").
           select("DISTINCT tags.*")

# usage
tags.each {|tag| puts tag.name}
```

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: hmm - still learning rails here -- how would I implement this code in a scope or something?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? (sidenote: don't create classes `Tag` and `Tagging` in your code, there can be conflicts from AATO)

Comment: well - ideally, I'd want a Tag.topic to return a hash including all the topics tags.. only ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag and the relevant tags database doesn't store the context of the tag -- only taggings does.

Comment: When I try this I get an SQL error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'taggings.context' in 'where clause': SELECT DISTINCT tags.* FROM 'tags' WHERE (taggings.context = 'topics')`

Comment: Works with joins, but not with includes

Answer (score 0):

Use `Model.tag_counts` (from [Using acts-as-taggable-on how do I find the top, say 10, tags in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451179/using-acts-as-taggable-on-how-do-i-find-the-top-say-10-tags-in-my-app)):

```
User.skill_counts # => [<Tag name="joking" count=2>,<Tag name="clowning" count=1>...]
```

Comment: The performance for this is [pretty horrible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238282/get-all-tags-by-context-for-acts-as-taggable-on), the above solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.includes(:taggings).where(taggings:{context:'topics'}).uniq(:name).order(:name)
```

One limitation when doing `joins` or `includes` with a tagging context is that you will only see topics that are active. You cannot load up a topic list and have them show up using this query. See examples:

**Without tagging context**

```
2.2.1 :009 > ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.includes(:taggings)
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags`
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `taggings`.* FROM `taggings` WHERE `taggings`.`tag_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
[
    [0] severe hearing loss {
                    :id => 1,
                  :name => "severe hearing loss",
        :taggings_count => 0
    },
    [1] hearing loss {
                    :id => 2,
                  :name => "hearing loss",
        :taggings_count => 1
    },
    [2] hearing aids {
                    :id => 3,
                  :name => "hearing aids",
        :taggings_count => 0
    }
]
```

**With taggings context of `topics`**

```
2.2.1 :016 > ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.includes(:taggings).where(taggings:{context:'topics'})
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.`id` AS t0_r0, `tags`.`name` AS t0_r1, `tags`.`taggings_count` AS t0_r2, `taggings`.`id` AS t1_r0, `taggings`.`tag_id` AS t1_r1, `taggings`.`taggable_id` AS t1_r2, `taggings`.`taggable_type` AS t1_r3, `taggings`.`tagger_id` AS t1_r4, `taggings`.`tagger_type` AS t1_r5, `taggings`.`context` AS t1_r6, `taggings`.`created_at` AS t1_r7 FROM `tags` LEFT OUTER JOIN `taggings` ON `taggings`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` WHERE `taggings`.`context` = 'topics'
[
    [0] hearing loss {
                    :id => 2,
                  :name => "hearing loss",
        :taggings_count => 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

The method is very simple:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.for_context('topics')
```

Comment: didn't work: NoMethodError: undefined method `for_context' for #<Class:0x007f467ad92ed0>