# Using acts-as-taggable-on how do I find the top, say 10, tags in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

Basically, I want to sort all the tags by the number of taggings they have.

I am trying to create navigation using the tags. So I want to display just the top 5, 10, 15, X tags sorted by the number of items they have tagged.

So I can't do any operation on a model, and there isn't a controller I can do it in either - I may just have to do it in the navigation view partial.

But I don't even know how to query acts-as-taggable-on to allow me to find the top X tags in the system.

How do I do that with acts-as-taggable-on?

I tried `Tag` model, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Edit 1**

When I call `Item.tag_counts`, this is what I see:

```
> Item.tag_counts
   (17.4ms)  SELECT items.id FROM "items" 
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (17.1ms)  SELECT tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM "tags" JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM "taggings" INNER JOIN items ON items.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Item' AND taggings.context = 'tags') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN(13)) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
 => [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "paper">, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "notepad">]
```

Which is the 2 tags in the system. Is it ordered? How can I tell how many items were tagged by each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tag_counts on the model class to retrieve a list of tags and their individual count.

Example with User model with default "skill" scope (courtesy of [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/#Usage)).

```
User.skill_counts # => [<Tag name="joking" count=2>,<Tag name="clowning" count=1>...]
```

You may also use `tag_counts_on(scope, options)` which is basically the same.

Also, there is a [RailsCast on this topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging), explaning this gem:

**EDIT after question edition:**
The list you have with `Item.tag_counts` is a list of tags having a `count` attribute.
I am not sure they are already sorted but you can sort them by this attribute like this:

```
tags = Item.tag_counts.sort_by {|tag| tag.count}
```

**EDIT for Final Answer Purposes**

Or the Rails 3 version of the above query:

```
tags = Item.tag_counts.order(:count)
```

Comment: Yeh, I get that. But I want overall `tag_counts`. Not on 1 `User`. I am trying to build navigation and I want to put the tags in my navigation. I don't want to put every tag, I just want to put say the top 5, 10, 15 tags.

Comment: Are you sure you call tag_counts on the model class or on a model instance ?

According to the quoted documentation, calling it on the class should do the trick.

Comment: I tried it myself on rails command, the returned tags have a overall count attribute. Updated my answer.

Comment: Or even more elegant and more Rails3-y,: `Item.tag_counts.order(:count)`. I have confirmed that your suggestion works. Thanks. Just what the doctor ordered!